# Would they call it a "rent" in English?

Tags: word-choice

What if I own a house or an apartment, but I still need to pay to the state every month for providing water and electricity to my house. Would they still refer to it as "rent" (Like "You need to pay the rent.") or should this be another word?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Water and electricity are called **utilities**.

> I must pay for utilities.
>
> The renter must pay the utilities.
>
> The renter is responsible for paying the utility bills. They are not included in the rent.
>
> Utilities are included in the rent. The landlord pays the utilities.

Comment: It depends on which variant of English you are speaking. In BrE we often call the companies that provide services such as water, gas  and electricity utilities companies and yet refer to paying the electricity bill or gas bill, water is sometimes referred to as the water rates as for many decades water was provided at flat rates rather than metered usage although many houses now have meters. Some people now use the term water bills.

Answer (score 1):

Rent is money you pay to use something temporarily rather than buy and own it.  If you rent a house, you live there for some duration in exchange for a payment.  It can also mean that you own the house and rent it out to someone else (the reverse situation).

As the owner, things you have to pay for, like real estate taxes, water, and electricity, would be **expenses**.  If you are talking only about water and electricity, those would be utilities.

The question is a little ambiguous as to who you're referring to as needing to pay.  If you own the property and charge the renter for certain costs for things they use, like water and electricity, there would be several ways to express that.

If you itemize what the renter pays you, you might say, "You need to pay rent plus utilities."  If you include a fixed amount in the rent to cover the average cost of utilities, you would refer to the total amount as "rent".

Comment: In BrE, paying for household expenses other than rent (e.g. phone, gas, electricity, water, local tax, internet, etc), is often called "paying the bills". I had a boss once who used to say periodically to the department, "if you can't decide whether to do some work, or stand around chatting, choose the one that pays the bills".

Comment: @MichaelH - That expression is often used in AmE, too.